# Model object validates (TryValidateModel) but does not update (TryUpdateModel)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, validation, updatemodel

The Model object refuses to update on production server but has no issues on development machine.  For the purposes of testing, I retrieve the model object and then immediately check its validation and update states, for example:

```
        Timesheet timesheet = _timesheetRepository.GetTimesheet(timesheetId);
        Helpers.ErrorHandler check = new Helpers.ErrorHandler();
        check.write("can I validate immediately? :- ", TryValidateModel(timesheet).ToString());
        check.write("can I save immediately? :- ", TryUpdateModel(timesheet).ToString());
```

TryValidateModel - returns true
TryUpdateModel   - returns false

Any recommendations?

Comment: What does ModelState.Errors have in it after the TryUpdateModel? This should be where it puts any errors that occurred.  Or try UpdateModel and catch the exception and see what it says.

Comment: Seem to have a date binding issue - which would explain variation across machines - localisation issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation and binding are different. Invalid data can often be bound (this is a feature; it makes re-displaying a page in the case of an error *much* easier), and "valid" (per your validation rules, if any) data sometimes can't be bound, due to typing conflicts.

Comment: Yes I appreciate the concepts of validation and binding, its a cornerstone of WPF but more-so the question is how to go about debugging and isolating the problem?

Comment: Personally I debug binding by [building MVC with source](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/02/03/using-the-aspnet-mvc-source-code-to-debug-your-app/) and tracing through it.

Comment: Nice.  This is what I need as I have debugged down to the metadata with no exceptions showing - thanks a million!